# Dpkg: error processing package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

So I am new to Ubuntu and I am currently busy installing python packages for a project. When I tried to run 'sudo get-apt upgrade', the following dpkg:error popped up.

I have tried a lot of commands to try and fix this problem.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
sudo dpkg --configure -a
for pkg in `dpkg --get-selections | egrep -v 'deinstall' | egrep 
python | awk '{print $1}'`; do  apt-get -y --force-yes install --
reinstall $pkg ; done <- This command just created more errors.
```

Any advice on how I can possibly fix this error? Thanks.

This is the terminal output when I ran the following command:

```
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,905 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package python-pil:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a 
previous failure.


......


Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pil:amd64
 python-pil.imagetk:amd64
 asymptote
 ipython
 ipython-notebook
 libboost-mpi-python1.58.0
 libboost-python1.58-dev
 python-antlr
 python-bs4
 python-cairo
 python-chardet
 python-cvxopt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I did ran a audit command and got the following:

```
~$ sudo dpkg --audit 
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
ipython              enhanced interactive Python shell
ipython-notebook     interactive Python html notebook
libboost-mpi-python1.58.0 C++ interface to the Message Passing    Interface (MPI)
libboost-python1.58-dev Boost.Python Library development files
python-antlr         language tool for constructing recognizers,    compilers etc
python-bs4           error-tolerant HTML parser for Python
python-cairo         Python bindings for the Cairo vector graphics    library
python-chardet       universal character encoding detector for Python2
python-cvxopt        Python package for convex optimization
python-pil:amd64     Python Imaging Library (Pillow fork)

The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
asymptote            script-based vector graphics language inspired by       MetaPos

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried    using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
python-jinja2        small but fast and easy to use stand-alone    template engin
python-markupsafe    HTML/XHTML/XML string library for Python
python-pil.imagetk:amd64 Python Imaging Library - ImageTk Module    (Pillow fork)
```